# How do I loop through all files in a folder using C?

Tags: c

I want to remove a particular substring from all the file names in a directory:

> -- like 'XYZ.com' from 'Futurama s1e20 - [XYZ.com].avi' --

So basically I need to provide the method with a desired substring, and it has to loop through all file names and compare.

I cant figure out how to loop through all files in a folder using C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`FTS(3)`](https://manpage.me/?q=fts) to loop through all files in a folder using C:

http://keramida.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/fts3-or-avoiding-to-reinvent-the-wheel/

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 struct dirent *dp;
 DIR *dfd;

 char *dir ;
 dir = argv[1] ;

 if ( argc == 1 )
 {
  printf("Usage: %s dirname\n",argv[0]);
  return 0;
 }

 if ((dfd = opendir(dir)) == NULL)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", dir);
  return 0;
 }

 char filename_qfd[100] ;
 char new_name_qfd[100] ;

 while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL)
 {
  struct stat stbuf ;
  sprintf( filename_qfd , "%s/%s",dir,dp->d_name) ;
  if( stat(filename_qfd,&stbuf ) == -1 )
  {
   printf("Unable to stat file: %s\n",filename_qfd) ;
   continue ;
  }

  if ( ( stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT ) == S_IFDIR )
  {
   continue;
   // Skip directories
  }
  else
  {
   char* new_name = get_new_name( dp->d_name ) ;// returns the new string
                                                   // after removing reqd part
   sprintf(new_name_qfd,"%s/%s",dir,new_name) ;
   rename( filename_qfd , new_name_qfd ) ;
  }
 }
}
```

Although I would personally prefer a script to do this job like

```
#!/bin/bash -f
dir=$1
for file in `ls $dir`
do
 if [ -f $dir/$file ];then
  new_name=`echo "$file" | sed s:to_change::g`
  mv $dir/$file $dir/$new_name
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer will get me down-voted, but your problem is perfect for a shell script, (or .cmd script), a PHP script, or PERL script. Doing it in C is more work than the problem is worth.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [dirent.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h).

Answer (score 2):

The key functions are _findfirst, _findnext and _findclose

```
struct _finddata_t file_info;
char discard[] = "XYZ.com";
char dir[256] = "c:\\folder\\";
char old_path[256];
char new_path[256];
intptr_t handle = 0;

memset(&file_info,0,sizeof(file_info));

strcpy(old_path,dir);
strcat(old_path,"*.avi");

handle = _findfirst(old_path,&file_info);
if (handle != -1)
{
    do
    {
        char *new_name = NULL;
        char *found = NULL;
        new_name = strdup(file_info.name);
        while ((found = strstr(new_name,discard)) != 0)
        {
            int pos = found - new_name;
            char* temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(new_name));
            char* remain = found+strlen(discard);
            temp[pos] = '\0';
            memcpy(temp,new_name,pos);
            strcat(temp+pos,remain);
            memcpy(new_name,temp,strlen(new_name));
            free(temp);
        }
        strcpy(old_path,dir);
        strcat(old_path,file_info.name);
        strcpy(new_path,dir);
        strcat(new_path,new_name);
        rename(old_path,new_path);
        free(new_name);
    }while(_findnext(handle,&file_info) != -1);
}
    _findclose(handle);
```

Comment: The API is different under Linxu / Unix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dirent.h` for POSIX systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// POSIX
#include <dirent.h>


#define MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE 256


int read_directories(const char* path) {
    DIR* directory = opendir(path);
    if (directory == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct dirent* entry = NULL;
    while ((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
        char full_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE] = { 0 };
        snprintf(full_name, MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            // Recurse unless the directory is the current (".") or parent ("..") directory.
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                printf("'%s' is a directory\n", full_name);
                read_directories(full_name);
            }
        } else {
            printf("'%s' is a file\n", full_name);
        }
    }

    closedir(directory);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int main(int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Must provide at most one path\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const char* path = argv[1];
    return read_directories(path);
}
```

Example running the executable in the terminal:

```bash
cc main.c -o main && ./main .
```

Answer (score 1):

`fts` has a nice interface, but it's 4.4BSD and is not portable.  (I recently got bitten in the rear by some software with an inherent dependency on fts.)  `opendir` and `readdir` are less fun but are POSIX standards and are portable.