# loop inside a directory and get its files in c

Tags: c, linux, file, directory

I am new to C and It might be a simple question.
I want to loop through filenames and ignore subfolder and its files. I have
to display the files dirent information.

Please help me how to do it using C.

thanks,

Comment: Maybe something from here will help: [How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Comment: Search "readdir c exemple" on google, there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: this is [very simple and efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the files in a directory. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271064/how-do-i-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-c) answer it can give you good input. there are many questions relating to this concept of reading files in a directory in C in stackoverflow itself read those.