# changing multiple file names at once

Tags: c

I have multiple files in a directory, ending with the same name *.html.html, I'm looking for a way to get their names and change them to just *.html using the `rename()` function in c or c++ or any other way to solve this problem

Comment: "*or any other way to solve this problem*" which platform are you on?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in C? Your OS is likely to have a command for doing that

Comment: Use a shell script. It would be a lot easier. What OS are you using?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102647/10947

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, I've tried to do that in cmd  but it's not working the way I like

Comment: Have you tried: `rename *.html.html *.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In command line, simply use:

```
ren *.html.html *.html
```

Or, in PowerShell:

```
Dir *.html.html | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "html") }
```

Shell would be the simplest option and the most sensate to use. Using C would be overkilling it. Any scripting language (python, php) would be a simpler solution.

If you really really just want to do it in C, you can have a look at this SO question: [How do I loop through all files in a folder using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271064/how-do-i-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-c)

Comment: Have you tested the "ren *.html.html *.html" solution?

Comment: cmd and PowerShell are not working for me,my file name is ending with ".html" and has .html extension, I want to get rid of the additional .html to end up with just one .html