# How to iterate over directory contents in Squirrel-lang?

Tags: directory, filesystems, squirrel

I need to use Squirrel-lang for a college assignment, and I have to count the files in a directory tree using threads. I've got the treading under control, but I can't for the life of me find any useful information on how to navigate directories in this language. So far I've only managed to figure out that I can open a directory as a file (Which makes sense in an UNIX system) using

```
local currDirr = file(".", "r");
```

But the Squirrel documentation is incredibly vague regarding its filesystem API and any similar questions I could find on the matter are 10+yrs old, when Squirrel didn't even have an IO library yet. Does anyone know how I could traverse the filesystem here? Or at least point me in a direction to embed some C/C++ code that lets me do this through Squirrel's C API.

Thanks in advance

PD: Just in case anyone wonders why I have to use Squirrel specifically, the assignment is to solve 2 threading-related problems with a language whose name has the same number of letters as yours. Squirrel was the closest thing I could find to a general purpose language with 8 letters that had more than 5 sentences written about it online. If anyone knows of another language that would be better suited for this, said suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late. You can check the [minimal implementation](https://github.com/albertodemichelis/squirrel/blob/master/etc/minimal.c) of the language in the official repository. On top of it, you can register your own functions in the root table. The docs provide an example:

```c
SQInteger register_global_func(HSQUIRRELVM v, SQFUNCTION f, const char* fname)
{
    sq_pushroottable(v);
    sq_pushstring(v, fname, -1);
    sq_newclosure(v, f, 0); //create a new function
    sq_newslot(v, -3, SQFalse);
    sq_pop(v, 1); //pops the root table
    return 0;
}

register_global_func(v, myfunc, _SC("myfunc"));
```

So you can register a function like the ones suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271064/how-do-i-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-c) question.